# Assigning New Column's Value From a List of Values Warning For Large DataSets - Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I have a list of Data Frames like this:

```
sm = pd.DataFrame([["Forever", 'BenHarper'],["Steel My Kisses", 'Kack Johnson'],\
                  ["Diamond On the Inside",'Xavier Rudd'],[ "Count On Me", "Bruno Mars"]],\
                   columns=["Song", "Artist"])

pm = pd.DataFrame([["I am yours", 'Jack Johnson'],["Chasing Cars", 'Snow Patrol'],\
                  ["Kingdom Comes",'Cold Play'],[ "Time of your life", "GreenDay"]],\
                   columns=["Song", "Artist"])

df_list = [sm,pm]
```

Now, I have another list of values that I like to assign as a new column to Data Frames in my list of Data Frames.

```
years = ["1999", "2003"]
```

I used the following code, (it works okay for smaller data sets)

```
df_with_year = []
for df in df_list:
    for j in years:
        df["Year"] = j
    df_with_year.append(df)
```

However, when I use this same logic for bigger dataset, I am getting an error:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Any ideas why I am getting this Copying error. I went through the provided link, it talks about a column that already exists, in which case I can use `.loc`. In my case, I am creating a new column and assigning values.

Comment: It's not an error, just a warning. Have you checked if your datasets were modified in the desired way?

Comment: @xyzjayne yes, I did. And Only thing I am thinking is to divide into smaller chinks. Probably taking 10 dataframes at a time.

Comment: @sacul  Your posted answer with enumeration method was faster, but still has the warning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Datafame `df` is itself a sub-DataFrame of some other `parent_df`, this
`SettingWithCopyWarning` is often triggered by lines like `df["Year"] = j` or even `df.loc[:, "Year"] = j`.
As long as you are not trying to use `df["Year"] = j` as a way to modify `parent_df`, you can always safely ignore 
`SettingWithCopyWarning`.

If you'd rather not see the warning anyway, you can silence it globally by setting

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Comment: This makes much sense now!